# Create Delivery Plan styling rules using Azure Devops REST Apis

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create Delivery plan in the Azure Devops project using Azure Devops REST Apis. I have used following method to create the same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/plans/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

POST [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/work/plans?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/work/plans?api-version=6.0)

and I am sending following data in the request body properties

```
{
    "properties": {
        "teamBacklogMappings": [
            {
                "teamId": "09d57738-697f-4433-abdd-b80a2bc6337b",
                "categoryReferenceName": "Microsoft.RequirementCategory"
            },
            {
                "teamId": "5df45eec-4108-474a-8d93-bc09c0b9037e",
                "categoryReferenceName": "Microsoft.RequirementCategory"
            },
            {
                "teamId": "e8ed402b-68e7-4140-96f2-07790a08788b",
                "categoryReferenceName": "Microsoft.RequirementCategory"
            },
            {
                "teamId": "14425694-efa5-454e-811c-e9e03d79198f",
                "categoryReferenceName": "Microsoft.RequirementCategory"
            },
            {
                "teamId": "b02690e9-1f48-421a-a918-3b23cc9a1b73",
                "categoryReferenceName": "Microsoft.RequirementCategory"
            }
        ],
        "cardSettings": {
            "fields": {
                "showId": true,
                "showAssignedTo": true,
                "assignedToDisplayFormat": "avatarOnly",
                "showState": true,
                "showTags": true,
                "showParent": false,
                "showEmptyFields": true,
                "showChildRollup": true,
                "additionalFields": null,
                "coreFields": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "System.AssignedTo",
                        "displayName": "Assigned To",
                        "fieldType": "string",
                        "isIdentity": true
                    },
                    {
                        "referenceName": "System.Id",
                        "displayName": "ID",
                        "fieldType": "integer",
                        "isIdentity": false
                    },
                    {
                        "referenceName": "System.State",
                        "displayName": "State",
                        "fieldType": "string",
                        "isIdentity": false
                    },
                    {
                        "referenceName": "System.Tags",
                        "displayName": "Tags",
                        "fieldType": "plainText",
                        "isIdentity": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "markers": [],
        "styleSettings": [
            {
                "name": "BLOCKER",
                "isEnabled": "True",
                "filter": "[System.Tags] CONTAINS 'BLOCKER'",
                "clauses": [
                    {
                        "fieldName": "System.Tags",
                        "logicalOperator": "AND",
                        "operator": "CONTAINS",
                        "value": "BLOCKER"
                    }
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "background-color": "#E60017",
                    "title-color": "#000000"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "New",
                "isEnabled": "True",
                "filter": "[System.State] = 'New'",
                "clauses": [
                    {
                        "fieldName": "System.State",
                        "logicalOperator": "AND",
                        "operator": "=",
                        "value": "New"
                    }
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "background-color": "#AAAAAA",
                    "title-color": "#000000"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Dev Completed",
                "isEnabled": "True",
                "filter": "[System.State] = 'Development Completed'",
                "clauses": [
                    {
                        "fieldName": "System.State",
                        "logicalOperator": "AND",
                        "operator": "=",
                        "value": "Development Completed"
                    }
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "background-color": "#D7E587",
                    "title-color": "#000000"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Deployed to QA",
                "isEnabled": "True",
                "filter": "[System.State] = 'Deployed to QA (SIT)'",
                "clauses": [
                    {
                        "fieldName": "System.State",
                        "logicalOperator": "AND",
                        "operator": "=",
                        "value": "Deployed to QA (SIT)"
                    }
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "background-color": "#C3D84C",
                    "title-color": "#000000"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Deployed to UAT",
                "isEnabled": "True",
                "filter": "[System.State] = 'Deployed to UAT'",
                "clauses": [
                    {
                        "fieldName": "System.State",
                        "logicalOperator": "AND",
                        "operator": "=",
                        "value": "Deployed to UAT"
                    }
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "background-color": "#60AF49",
                    "title-color": "#000000"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Deployed to PROD",
                "isEnabled": "True",
                "filter": "[System.State] = 'Completed'",
                "clauses": [
                    {
                        "fieldName": "System.State",
                        "logicalOperator": "AND",
                        "operator": "=",
                        "value": "Completed"
                    }
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "background-color": "#00643A",
                    "title-color": "#000000"
                }
            }
        ],
        "tagStyleSettings": []
    }
}
```

However Styling rules are not getting created in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Got this done by using Update for the Delivery plan immediately after creating the same. Update it with same properties though you will have to add revision property to the request body.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/plans/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/work/plans/{id}?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/work/plans/%7Bid%7D?api-version=6.0)

Answer (score 0):

Create Delivery Plan doesn't accept style settings, from the UI you can notice this:

[image]

Just get the plan id and the response from the [Create API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/plans/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and then use them in the [Update API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/plans/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), this is the only way.